# Ignoring empty href in jQuery each

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to ignore a's with empty href attributes in a jQuery function. Here's the Menu:

```
<nav id="nav-works-screen" role="navigation">
    <ul id="nav-other-links">
        <li class="nav-title">NICHOLAS<br/> AREHART</li><br/>
        <li><a href="">CV/Bio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php randLink() ?>">Link???</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="nav-works">
        <li class="nav-title">WORK</li><br/>
        <li class="work"><a href="#the-speech">The Speech</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="#forms-derived-from-a-code">Forms Derived from a Code</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="#unauthorized-reproduction">Unauthorized Reproduction</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="">Newport Ads</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="">An Illegally Downloaded Film</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="">Hold on to Your Genre</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="">Autonomy</a></li>
        <li class="work"><a href="">Ikea Objects</a></li><br/>
        <li id="nav-arrows"> 
            <div class="nav-arrows">
                <a class="nav-arrow-prev" href="">&laquo;</a>
            &emsp;&emsp;
                <a class="nav-arrow-next" href="">&#187;</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The anchors:

```
<div id="content" class="clrfx">

    <div id="primary" class="clrfx">
        <div id="the-speech" class="page odd the-speech">
            <div class="page-content">
                <h2>The Speech</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="forms-derived-from-a-code" class="page even forms-derived-from-a-code">
            <div class="page-content">
                <h2>Forms Derived from a Code</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="unauthorized-reproduction" class="page odd unauthorized-reproduction">
            <div class="page-content">
                <h2>Unauthorized Reproduction</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- #primary -->

</div><!-- #content -->
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#nav-works-screen a').smoothScroll();

        $(document).scroll( function(){
            $('nav a').each( function(){
                var workLink = $(this);
                var work = workLink.attr('href');

                if (work != '') {

                    var workTop = $(work).offset().top;
                    var currentPos = $(window).scrollTop();
                    var winHeight = $(window).height();

                    if (currentPos >= workTop) {
                        workLink.css({'background-color':'#38FF4F'});
                        workLink.parent().siblings().children().css({'background-color':'transparent'});
                    }
                    else {
                        workLink.css({'background-color':'transparent'});
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error that property 'top' of null cannot be read. I don't understand why the work variable would be empty if I've explicitly stated that any empty work variables should be ignored. I'm sure its something really simple but I've been banging my head against a wall with this thing for over an hour now. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit - This is the problem: `<li><a href="<?php randLink() ?>">Link???</a></li>` I guess my random link php function is screwing with jQuery traversing the DOM but I'm curious as to why.

Comment: I could not see any control with id = #the-speech in the posted html, Can you post that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Well that actually worked for me, but I had to change the selector

```
$('nav a').each( function(){
```

to

```
$('#nav-other-links a').each( function(){
```

because there is no "nav" element in your html extract.
But you should place an

```
alert(work);
```

right before the if-statement and check what "work" really is about at the moment of empty href, when it's not an empty string.

Comment: There is actually a nav element in the markup; I've added it to my original post. However, I am still getting the null error. I also changed the if statement to alert me whenever it had an href that was not empty. It returned 4 alerts as expected. I'm guessing the problem lies somewhere after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).scroll( function(){
        $('nav a').each( function(){
             // if the href evaluates to false then return false
             if(!$(this).attr('href')){return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the **attr not** selector?

```
$('#nav-other-links a[href!=""').each(function() {
    //
});
```

Also, Tomasz is right about the imaginary `NAV` selector.